# Merchante Category Code field in the transaction

Tags: transactions, yodlee

I am fetching transaction data using Yodlee developer APIs. I am trying to look for Merchant Category Code (MCC) in that transaction, however, I am not seeing it. As I understood, MCC is used by payment gateways (Visa/Mastercard/Amex, etc..) to categorize a transaction. I know Yodlee does its own categorization, however, I am interested in the MCC code. Does anyone know how to get the MCC codes? Many transactions I fetched had missing this.

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is returned in bank transaction data elements (i.e. BankTransactionData). please refer to [Bank Transaction](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Bank_Transaction) for more details. 
Please note that the level of availability for MCCode is "Rarely"; meaning only very few data providers(FIs) support this field.

Comment: I am not seeing this field when I pull credit card transactions? I am assuming bank transaction is different from card transactions. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, For Card transactions the frequency is "Sometimes" as compared to "Rarely" in Bank Transactions: [Check this](http://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Card_Transaction)

That means MCC still may or may not be present on end sites.  Also you may want to have a look at creating sub categories or user defined categories that can override Yodlee defined categories:  [Check this !](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/categorizeTransactions)

-Vishal